Suggested techniques to model forward moving averages
I want to start a personal project, but i'm failing to formulate my business problem into a model. I would love inputs on how to better look into this issue and what type of models/techniques i should be researching to tackle it.
I want to model the nth day forward moving average of a metric on a given date based on previous days and on the latest available forward moving average for that given day.
For example: Consider today is day 30 and I want to predict up to 360d forward moving average a metric.
I will only have the actual average value of the 360d forward moving average on day 360. Currently i have the actual average values for 1d to 30d. I also have all of these forward moving averages for the past 5 years. I also know that the variable has diminishing returns and is expected to plateau after 12-18 months.
The goal is to define ranges in for all forward moving averages from the latest date (31d) to 360d. These ranges should be update everyday given the new information.
I am failing to think of the type of model i'd be looking for or how should i structure the problem, given how the goal here is not to predict a single value, but all the values in the 31d to 360d range.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
